# Swift custom callback is not working on first instance but working on second instance

Tags: ios, swift, callback, uiswitch

I have following custom UIStackViewComponent

```
class TitleWithSwitchView: UIStackView {
    let title: String
    var onSwitchTapped: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.title = ""
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.title = ""
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private var label: UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.text = "-"
        return label
    }
    
    private lazy var labelTitle = {
        let label = label
        label.text = title
        return label
    }()
    
    private lazy var switchButton = {
        let switchButton = UISwitch()
        switchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTapped), for: .valueChanged)
        return switchButton
    }()
    
    @objc private func switchTapped() {
        onSwitchTapped?(switchButton.isOn)
    }
}
```

I have 2 instance of same component and the switch is only working on second instance. On first instance nothing happens

**Update :**

This is how I'm using this component. The second one works perfectly but the first one is not working

```
    private lazy var stackViewHobbyContainer = {
            let stack = TitleWithSwitchView(title: "Some Text")
            stack.onSwitchTapped = { [weak self] isOn in
                self?.onHobbyContainerSwitchChange(isOn: isOn)
            }
            return stack
        }()

private lazy var stackViewChallengeSwitchView = {
        let stack = TitleWithSwitchView(title: "Another Text?")
        stack.onSwitchTapped = { [weak self] isOn in
            print("Switch tapped \(isOn)")
        }
        return stack
    }()
```

Comment: In the provided code, you are creating a new `UILabel` each time you access the label computed property, which can cause issues when you have multiple instances of this class.

To fix this issue, you can try creating `labelTitle` and `switchButton` as stored properties with lazy initialization.

Comment: can you update the code?

Comment: The first thing I would check is whether the `switchTapped` action handler is being called for both switches by either adding a `print` or using a breakpoint. If that is being called, is `onSwitchTapped` somehow `nil`. Test the logic to try and work out where it fails. Add a print or breakpoint in `stackViewHobbyContainer`’s implementation of the closure. This will help diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: When I diagnosed it I found that switch event is not called for value changed.